# Checkstyle - whitelist of warnings to suppress

Tags: java, checkstyle, suppress-warnings

With the [SuppressWarnings](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_annotation.html#SuppressWarnings) check I'm able to specify what warning can not be suppressed. So in order not to allow `unchecked` suppressions:

```
<module name="SuppressWarnings">
  <property name="format" value="^unchecked$"/>
</module>
```

I try to do the opposite - I want to forbid all suppressions except `unchecked`. I tried:

```
<module name="SuppressWarnings">
  <property name="format" value="[^(unchecked)]"/>
</module>
```

But it doesn't work (it neither detects `unchecked` nor any other suppressions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/1005481), you can use a regular expression that matches anything *but* `unchecked` by configuring the check like this:

```xml
<module name="SuppressWarnings">
    <property name="format" value="^(?!unchecked).*$"/>
</module>
```

This regex construct is called a "zero-width negative lookahead". It is kind of cludgy to use; it would have been better if Checkstyle included an option to configure if you want a whitelist or a blacklist. But well, this works, too.

Comment: I needed to allow both `unchecked` and `nls` suppressions, so I used the `^(?!(unchecked)|(nls)).*$` pattern. Thank you.